# Is it possible to clear an array in .net core configurations?

Tags: .net-core, azure-webjobs

Right now I am configuring a system to monitor and do stuff with specific queues.  I need to configure a list of queues each queue handler should interact with, so I make an `appsettings.json` file that looks like:

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "Queues": [
            {
                "Name": "First",
                "Type": "Type1"
            }           ]
    }
}
```

The queues I will be handling while developing will be different than the queues machine X will be handling, which will be different than the queues machine Y will be handling.

Right now I'm deploying this system out on Azure as Webjobs, and using the app settings panel in Azure itself to override the application's settings via environment variables.

However, this breaks down on arrays.  Currently I am overriding by using the the `AppSettings:Queues:0:xxxxx` syntax and that works fine.  I can even add additional entries to the list via environment variables by changing the index in that syntax.

The issue is that during development I added an extra queue entry to the local `appsettings.json` file in order to test some new functionality.  After deployment, even though there was no `AppSettings:Queues:1:xxxxx` environment variable set it was still using the 2nd entry from the deployed `appsettings.json` file.

Is there any way to tell the overrides that I want a clean array?  This will cause uncertainty because we are unable to ensure that a developer won't add an entry for testing that will cause non-test environments to do incorrect things.  This will cause us not to be able to deploy `appsettings.json`, which means we have no way to deploy and manage sane defaults across all of our installations.

The only workaround is to come up with an arbitrary number (like 10) and create null overrides for them, but I believe this is just kicking the can down the road.

Comment: Did you consider using appsettings.Development.json during development?

Comment: I guess that's a good point to solve my overall scenario, but I still think this is a problem because it makes array overrides very sensitive and easy to get wrong.

Comment: only create the settings in appsettings.Development.json, keep the appsettings.json clear and use the appsettings in the Azure web app to store the production settings?

Comment: By using the appsettings from the web app you can even decide to not have any appsettings.json file at all which lowers the risk!

Comment: Yep I think that's the approach I'm going to take now that I think about it (though with some sane defaults in the main json file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

Move the settings to an `appsettings.Development.json`. You can then store the production settings

1. in appsettings.json
2. not publish the appsettings.json at all, and use the appsettings in the Azure web app:

[image: app settings in web app]

Bonus: instead of using `AppSettings:Queues:0:xxxxx` you can use the [IOptions feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration): create POCO's for your settings:

```
public class Settings
{
    public List<Queue> Queues { get; set; }
}

public class Queue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Inject them in your Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
}
```

And use them in your code as a list!

[image: Settings]

Comment: Yeah I use the `IOptions<>` injection stuff in the code itself, the `AppSettings:Queues:0:xxxxx` format is more for Azure setup and defining setting overrides in databases that are used in the configuration builder.